# If some of the arrays are empty

Tags: php, arrays

Well, i need to check if some fields are empty when submiting get an echo "fail";

For now i have this:

```
   $campos = array('nome', 'email');
    foreach ($campos as $a) {
         $$a = $_REQUEST[$a];
         if(isset($$a) && $$a != ""){

$post_vars = array('iphone3g1', 'iphone3g2', 'nome', 'iphone41', 'postal');
$post_values = array();
foreach($post_vars as $var) {
    $post_values[$var] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]). "'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (" . implode(',', array_keys($post_values)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', array_values($post_values)) . ")";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if($query==TRUE){

    $to=$apelido;
    $subject="iRepairApple";
    $header="from: iRepairApple <geral@iRepairApple.com> ";
    $message="Caro $nome , obrigado por preferir a iRepairApple! \r\n\n";
    $message.="O seu pedido de reparação foi registado. \r\n";
    $message.="Modelo p/ Reparação: $modelo; \r\n \n\n Deverá proceder à entrega do equipamento numa das nossas lojas (Ver Moradas)  \r\n";
    $message.="O seu código de reparação é o : \n $codigounico; \n\n Ao contactar a iRepairApple faça sempre referência a este código.";
    $message.="\n Com os melhores cumprimentos, \n A equipa iRepairApple.";

    $enviado = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    header('Location: ../index.php?mensagem=2');}


    }else{
        echo ("error");
        }
}

?>
```

(Would be the same as !empty)

It works, if none of the fields is filled it will retrieve the error, but if ONLY one is fulfilled it will tell it is ok :(. I will later put a header where i have echo ("error");

Comment: What are you doing after this `if(isset($$a) && $$a != ""){` show some more code

Comment: added code is not sufficient to answer to your question

Comment: I don't think it's relevant but i have edited the post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two to three of the new lines are very relevant. But the others aren't. You should always try to simplify your problem by taking things away, etc. until you have the simplest possible example where the error still occurs. This will really help you find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is to check wheter the `$_REQUEST` array contains all the fields denoted in `$campos`? The relevant part of your code is missing, but it looks like the `if` clause is supposed to do the check.

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, here's one way to do it:

```
foreach ($campos as $a) {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$a]) ||
        ($$a = $_REQUEST[$a]) == "") {
        die("Field {$a} not set.");
    }
}
echo "Ok.";
```

Note that you have to use `isset()` on the `$_REQUEST` array and not on the `$aa` variable. Maybe you also want to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of the `$_REQUEST` superglobal.

Comment: This works as well, iluwatar's code works fine too. But i will use yours to keep it smaller. Thank you very much svens ;)

Answer (score 0):

So you just reverse the condition to check if one or more of the fields are empty and echo failure in that case.

```
$campos = array('nome', 'email');
foreach ($campos as $a) 
{
  $$a = $_REQUEST[$a];
  if(!isset($$a) || $$a == "")
  {
    echo "fail";
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's a very clever solution ;). Well done sir. I will give it a try! (Upvoting) Edit: Can't, someone downvoted my post and now i don't have the 15 necessary points :/